# Three.js Illusion: how to rescale and reposition object

Tags: 3d, three.js, perspective, perspectivecamera

> **Duplicate post** [whats the formula to point along line known starting point, ending point and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131422/whats-the-formula-to-point-along-line-known-starting-point-ending-point-and-dis)

I want to create a eye illusion with perspective view for objects. I want to show perspective of the object as it should be. There is a simple example in the following link.

http://jsfiddle.net/omerfarukz/32TLZ/6/

The central object is smaller and closer than the others, but at the end of the simulation, it appears the same size as the others.

I manually computed the size and z-coordinate of the central object. My question is: How to calculate the size and z-coordinate of the central object ​​programmatically?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.8, 100)

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = 5;
camera.position.y = 5;
//camera.toOrthographic();

var cubes = [];

var defaultSize = 1;
for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8, 10, 10);
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cube.position.x = (x % 10) * 2;
        cube.position.y = (y % 10) * 2;

        if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
            var tmpZ = 15; //(Math.random() * 10);

            var newSize = 0.26;
            cube.scale.x = newSize;
            cube.scale.y = newSize;
            cube.scale.z = newSize;

            cube.position.x += 2.25;
            cube.position.y += 2.17;

            cube.position.z = tmpZ;
            console.log(tmpZ);
        }



        scene.add(cube);

        cubes.push(cube);
    }
}

camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.x = 30;
camera.position.z = 20;


function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
        //cubes[i].rotation.x += 0.001;
        //cubes[i].rotation.y += 0.001;
    }

    if (camera.position.x > 5) camera.position.x -= 0.1;
    if (camera.position.y > 5) camera.position.y -= 0.1;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

}
render();
```

Comment: figured some images to make easy understanding. please check followin images: [state a](http://zor.lu/temp/10.png) and [state b](http://zor.lu/temp/12.png) and [state c](http://zor.lu/temp/14.png) and [state d](http://zor.lu/temp/16.png) and [state e](http://zor.lu/temp/18.png) and [state f](http://zor.lu/temp/20.png)

Comment: The central object can be positioned at any point on the line segement from the camera's final position to the "center". The scale of the central object must equal (the distance from the camera's final position to the central object position) / (the distance from the camera's final position to the "center").